# Exchange Web Services Autodiscover non default link

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am writing a piece of software that runs on a utility device on a customers network, but not on the domain.  The autodiscover service is not available off domain the same as it is either on the domain or even on the internet.  None of the ways the service works by default will find it according to the docs, but the customer's IT staff tells me, supposedly :/ , it will all work if I can access Autodiscover at the link they gave me.  Is there any way to override the default approach and pass it this url to autodiscover from?  Hardcoding the link to /exchange.asmx is not an option nor is adding this device to the domain.

I am reusing, and now tweaking, a tried and true piece of software that has been deployed many times, but this situation is a first.

Answer (score 1):

Using the EWS Managed API you may be able to do it using the [AutodiscoverService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.autodiscover.autodiscoverservice%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) class.  It has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd636261%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) that takes the URI of the Autodiscover service as a parameter.

Your code should look something like this.  Note that I disable SCP lookup as you are not on a domain.  I have not actually tried this code but give it a try:

```
AutodiscoverService ads = new AutodiscoverService(new Uri("..."));
ads.EnableScpLookup = false;
ads.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(...);
ads.RedirectionUrlValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
GetUserSettingsResponse grResp = ads.GetUserSettings("someemail@domain.com", UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl);
Uri casURI = new Uri(grResp.Settings[UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl].ToString());

var service = new ExchangeService()
{
    Url = casURI,
    Credentials = ads.Credentials,
};
```